# Laptop Crashing when using Make - Possible Thermal Issues?

Tags: 20.04, crash, thinkpad, overheating, thinkfan

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.2 on a Lenovo Thinkpad P52s and *sometimes* run into issues when I use the `make` command with multiple cores (using the `-j` flag). My screen will freeze and the laptop will become completely unresponsive, requiring a forced shutdown in order to bring it back to life. I have left it for a couple hours before in hopes that it will eventually become responsive again, but to no avail. This has happened on the same laptop running Ubuntu 16.04 and I believe 18.04 as well. Each new install is a fresh install rather than upgrading using the release upgrade tool.

I suspect thermal issues due to the CPU temperatures hitting somewhere in the realm of 75 C at the time of the crash and the fact that using a box fan to actively cool the laptop lowers my chances of crashing. I have installed `thinkfan` to get the CPU fan working more frequently at lower temperatures and believe that it has helped, but that could be my own confirmation bias.

EDIT:

As for the code that I am compiling with `make`, it is some custom code which heavily utilizes the [GTSAM Library](https://gtsam.org/). GTSAM makes use of the Eigen and boost libraries as well. However, in the past, it seemed like arbitrary calls to `make` have caused issues as well. Unfortunately I do not recall what I was trying to build, but it was likely one of several ROS packages. I will look for some arbitrary code to compile with `make` to verify that my problem is agnostic to the specific project I have been working on recently.

Comment: @Nmath Thank you for the feedback. I have edited my question and will also attempt to build some arbitrary projects to verify whether or not the problem exists in my specific project.

Comment: Have you validated your RAM recently?  Multithreaded make can fill up whatever RAM is available, forcing swap, so check your disk also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System "freezes" are often caused by running too many, too large programs and running out of available memory. Use `free` to see if you have swap space, read `man mkswap swapon fstab` to create some. Swap space must be contiguous. use `mkswap` or `fallocate`, not `dd`. Traditionally, swap space of 1.5 × RAM has been recommended,  but YMMV. If you don't plan to hibernate your system, you can have less than 1.0 × RAM.

Comment: While I will need to run some more tests to confirm, increasing my swap size may have done the trick. My installation only had a 2GB swap file but I increased it to 1.0 × RAM = 8GB. To increase the swap size, I followed the instructions found [here](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-20-04/).